# How to use html option tag and check which option is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, scroller

I am trying to add a scroller feature to my website. The  tag works well for this and I want to load a new website if an option is selected. Heres what I currently have.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
                        $('#button').click(function(){
                                var val = document.getElementById("scroll");
                                                       if(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value == 1){
                                                       window.location.replace("/passbook.html");
                                                       }else if(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value == 2){
                                                       window.location.replace("/settings.html");
                                                       }
                                                       });
                                           });
                        });
    </script>

<select id="scroll" style="height:50px; width:150px;" >
<optgroup label="Home">
<option value="0" >Home</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Page" >
<option value="1" >Page</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Other" >
<option value="2" >Settings</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<button type="button">Go</button>
</body>
```

Right now nothing visibly happens when go is clicked. I would like a redirect to those pages. I know that window.location.replace(Your URL Here) works. Can someone help me with the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! as far as i understood your question. If you want to redirect your client on option clicking then this might be helpfull

```
   <select id="opts" onchange="GotoPage()">
        <option value="0">SELECT</option>
        <option value="index.html">Home</option>
        <option value="page.html">Page</option>
        <option value="setting.html">Setting</option>
        <option value="go.html">Go</option>
    </select>
```

In Script as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GotoPage()
{
   var loc = document.getElementById('opts').value;
   if(loc!="0")
   window.location = loc;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `name="scroll"` to select tag

take the value of options by `var val = $('select[name="scroll"] option:selected').text();`

```
<body>
    <select id="scroll" name="scroll" style="height:50px; width:150px;" >
    <optgroup label="Home">
    <option value="0" >Home</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Page" >
    <option value="1" >Page</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Other" >
    <option value="2" >Settings</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
    <button type="button">Go</button>
    </body>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
                        $('#button').click(function(){
                                var val = $('select[name="scroll"] option:selected').text();
                                                       if(val == 1){
                                                       window.location.replace("/passbook.html");
                                                       }else if(val == 2){
                                                       window.location.replace("/settings.html");
                                                       }
                                                       });
                                           });
                        });
    </script>
```